# Algorithm for selecting closest pairs using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been trying to solve this problem my professor has given me but couldn't make a proper solution. The following is the problem

**Problem:**
A rectangular circuit board has two parallel sides with width W between them. There are m terminals on the upper side of the board and n terminals (n < m) on the lower side. Let U[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgE3I.png) < U[2] < … < U[m] be the distances from the left end of the board to the m terminals on the upper side, respectively.  Let L[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgE3I.png) < L[2] < … < L[n] be the distances from the left end of the board to the n terminals on the lower side, respectively. Now, we need to select n terminals from the m terminals on the upper side to be connected to the n terminals on the lower side by n straight line segments, respectively, such that the total length of the n line segments is minimized. The following figure illustrates the problem for m = 8 and n = 4.

[image: Example]

(a) Prove that, in an optimal solution, any two line segments will not intersect.

(b) Design an O(mn) dynamic programming algorithm to solve this minimization problem. You need to define sub-problems, show the inductive formula, initial conditions, and a pseudocode. You can use d(i, j) to denote the distance between U[i] and L[j], 1 ≤ i ≤ m, 1 ≤ j ≤ n. (The calculation of d(i, j) =  ) can be omitted.

**My Approach:**

For the above problem, my approach was first to make a matrix d(i,j) where i are the terminals on the bottom and j are the terminals on the top. d(i,j) has all the distances from any two circuits.Then iterating through each row I will find the smallest distance and mark the respective terminal. But I am not sure this would work if the top circuits are all to the extreme right of the side. So can anyone provide me with a better approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that `d(i, j)` in this case is a pure function, simply the distance between `U[i]` and `L[j]`, it's trivial to calculate it, and it has nothing to do with time complexity or DP subproblems. The "hint" given with (a) is what leads to a DP solution, namely that once you get a connection from `L[j]` to `U[k]`, `L[j+1]` can only be connected to "`U[k+1]` or higher".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a recursive Dynamic Programming solution that uses memoisation, the complexity is O(mn), here at each recursive level we can either choose to join the current point defined in the U[] array with the point defined in the L[] array, or we can move forward without doing so:

```
#include<iostream>
#define INF 1e9

using namespace std;

int n, m, d[100][100], dp[100][100];

int solve(int idx1, int idx2){
    if(idx1 > m){
        if(idx2 < n) return INF;
        else return 0;
    }
    if(idx2 > n) return 0;
    if(dp[idx1][idx2] != -1) return dp[idx1][idx2];

    int v1, v2;

    //include current
    v1 = solve(idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1) + d[idx1][idx2];

    //do not include current
    v2 = solve(idx1 + 1, idx2);

    return dp[idx1][idx2] = min(v1, v2);
}

int main(){

    //enter the the distances

    for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++) for(int j = 0;j < 100;j++) dp[i][j] = -1;
    cout << solve(1, 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the part (a) of your question, let us assume that 2 line segments do intersect, then we cannot have an optimal solution because if we just swapped the 2 end points of the line segments defined by the L[] array then the distance would reduce, hence giving us a better solution.